# Executing stored procedures is not allowed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, coldfusion

I wrote a stored procedure for my application & can successfully run it in on my local. But while running the same application live it's throwing an error:

> Executing stored procedures is not allowed

Issue return while run the site.

This is my sample code :

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="countUsers" datasource="myDataSource" debug="yes" result="countResults">
    <!--- ClientID --->
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#customerID#" type="IN">
    <!--- LoggedInNow --->
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="1" type="IN">
    <cfprocresult name="qUsers" maxrows="5">
</cfstoredproc>
```

While dump the query result it's return data. But while test with live site it's return the below issue,

[image]

Note: But I can directly run the procedure in SQL Server directly with my same login.

Only the difference is in my local using cf11 but the live is in cf18.

Comment: `I can directly run`, `while test with live site` - this probably means that your login has required permissions whilst the login used by the site to connect to MSSQL does not have enough permissions.

Comment: You need to check the permissions of the SQL Server user that is being used to create the data source in CF Admin.

Comment: @Beginner. Thanks a lot. As per your suggestion I've set it in data source - > ( my datasource name) - > show advance setting -> check Stored Procedures check box in allowed sql options. Now I can access the store procedure. Thanks again.

Comment: You should write an answer with a screenshot of what you did thank way this question can be useful to the next person.

Comment: Sure I will do it now

Comment: For future readers: Most times you see an error message like "...is not allowed...", the first thing you should check is Permissions settings, whether in your application or in the database or wherever. Both should have explicit permissions set for specific users to do the actions required.  _Never_ let public users have unlimited db access and _don't use `sa` to connect cf  to your db_. Remember, too, that when you are performing an action on your app, that doesn't meant that it's necessarily your username trying to perform that entire action. Know your stack and how it talks to itself.

Comment: Yes.@Shawn. But I can run the store procedure directly in ms sql UI. So I though I used the same auth for coldfusion too while creation of data source. So I'm not thinking about permission setting on that time.  Thank you for your attention on these.

Comment: @Kannan.P Glad, it worked! Not related to your question but you seem to be still using `Application.cfm` on CF11/2018 instead of `Application.cfc`.

Comment: @Kannan.P If you want to use SSMS to query a SQL Server database, you can specify the login credentials. If you know those credentials, you can log in with them and test what your CF Query will actually see. Usually a developer will have more access rights than an application service account, so the query may run fine for you in SSMS as your user, but fail when run from the ColdFusion page. `cfquery` will run as the account set up in the datasource connection, which is another reason not to set up `sa` or other db admin account as your CF db account. Only give the minimum permissions needed.

Answer (score 5):

As per beginner suggestion, I've enable the stored procedure options in cf administrator. And I fixed that issue. To enable that options follow my below steps.

1. Go to cf admin
2. While add / edit the data source name
3. Click on show advance setting options
4. Now you can see Allowed SQL options. In that option you have number of check boxes. Here you have to check the stored procedures options
5. Click the submit button. Now check with your site the stored procedure gets run.

Please refer to this screen here:

[image]

Comment: You should be using a DB user with limited rights granted in production, but if that's not the case, you should uncheck items like `alter`, `grant`, `revoke`, `drop` and `create`. In the off chance someone manages a SQL Injection attack, you don't want to allow those commands to be run on your DB.

Comment: What @AdrianJ.Moreno said. Way too many times, when setting up a CF datasource, I've stuck with default permissions or just clicked everything or just used a user with dba permissions on the db. But that was mainly because I didn't understand the implications of what I was allowing. Those checkboxes can have very serious consequences. If you allow CF `DROP` permissions and the user has access to system tables, SQLi can cause a lot of problems that will hopefully end with only a major restore from backup. I can't really think of a good reason for an App server to have that much power.